# Monitor Git tag via Fastlane for automated build generation

Tags: ios, git, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I have integrated Fastlane into my app. It can generate builds automatically when I manually tell it to generate build via terminal. I was wondering is there a way where I can set the fastlane to keep monitoring my branch and start generating the builds whenever a new tag is created on my branch.

Comment: It took some setup but I got this working using Go CI, which monitors the repo for changes and then automatically builds. Fastlane itself doesn't have this feature as far as I'm aware, because it's not a long-running process in Terminal.

Comment: Yep, Fastlane doesn't support CI. I think I should go for Jenkins Or something similar to that.

Comment: But CI does support Fastlane ;)

Comment: hmmm okay. Still didn't fix which one to use.

Comment: You can use Fastlane with Jenkins, you just get Jenkins to trigger the Fastlane when a change occurs in your repo. I've done this very thing with Go CI. Fastlane is just a command line tool, so you just need whatever CI you use to run the command. This is what I do at home and at work, at work we use Team City, at home I use Go CI because it's free.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @KaneCheshire. Even I have setup the Jenkins. Now am struck in making the Jenkins flag the fastlane to take build whenever I Make a tag in GIT. I am pending with Jenkins to fastlane pipeline and Jenkins script that can monitor for new TAG

Comment: Could you @Manoj create an answer to your question and accept it, because I think you have get the right answer no?

Comment: @Sulfkain I have added the answer as per your request.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks, surelly this will help other users ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because Fastlane is not a CL (continuous integration). So there is no option to run it on the background like Jenkins does. I am using Jenkins for this to notify the Fastlane to trigger a lane when a New Tag is created on Git.